# Azure pipeline yaml: Cannot use strategy matrix variable in conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am having problem in calling template as the pre-condition is not getting satisfied, I am comparing parameter value to select which template to call at [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime), here I am having parameter value coming from strategy matrix and I think that might be the issue.

pipeline yaml :

```
stages:
- stage: build_stage
  jobs:
  - job:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        Dev_Build:
          build_type: "dev"
        Rel_Build:
          build_type: "rel"

    steps:
    - template: test_conditional_template.yml@templates_repo
      parameters:
        build: $(build_type)
```

test_conditional_template.yml :

```
parameters:
- name: build
  type: string
  default: 'dev'

steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.build, 'dev') }}:     # this condition is not working
 - template: test_conditional_template_generic.yml@templates_repo
   parameters:
    build_quality: ${{ parameters.build }}
```

test_conditional_template-generic.yml :

```
parameters:
- name: build
  type: string
  default: 'dev'

steps:
- script: |
    echo "build quality : ${{ parameters.build }}"
  displayName: "print build quality, test_conditional_template-generic"
```

I am not even able to compare the parameter value with normal script step too :

```
  - script: |
       echo "build quality : ${{ parameters.build }}"
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.build }}', 'dev')
```

This is what pipeline prints for above step :
[image]

if template is called with hard-coded parameter value, condition works fine :

```
steps:
- template: test_conditional_template.yml@templates_repo
  parameters:
    build: 'dev'   #this works fine with above template code
```

we're avoiding so much of boilerplate code with usage of strategy matrix so dont really want to get away from it, any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment but my first thought was that it's comparing 'dev' with "dev" in the first example and ''dev'' (double single quotes) in the script example, so both would evaluate as false,

I've been writing quite a few templates and have had a lot of similar issues, it would be nice if we could find out before checking the code in but ehh yaml...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).